# Create an EJB Jar without an IDE

Tags: eclipse, jar, ejb

I am exporting a project as an EJB Jar manually through Eclipse at the moment by right-clicking on the project and exporting.

Is it possible to create an identical jar file through the command line without having to rely on the IDE?

I have tried jar'ing but it doesn't seem to be capturing the same directory structure as the manual export does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. An ejb-jar is a normal .jar file in the end.

So for simple cases you can even use `ant` with the `jar` task: If you only have classes with or without a standard `ejb-jar.xml` descriptor, this is sufficient.

For example

```xml
    <jar destfile="${dist-directory}/${sb-jar}">
        <fileset dir="${sb-root}/classes">
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>

        <!-- META-INF/ejb-jar.xml etc. -->
        <fileset dir="packaging-data/sb-jar">
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>
    </jar>
```

You might have to adjust the `filesets`, and sometimes I even rearrange the project layout to make it easier for `ant` (this can be cumbersome).

There is a more sophisticated `ejbjar` task available as well, this one supports vendor specific elements to create ejb-jar files for different application servers: See [ant tasks for EJB](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ejb.html)